# Accessing column names in mutate_at()

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to apply the same function over multiple columns of a data frame in R.

I have a separate data frame which has some of the columns in the master data frame. When the column in the master data frame is in the other data frame, I want to add those two columns together, but I cannot seem to work out how to access each column name in the mutate_at() list.

```
# random secondary data frame
random <- data.frame(y = rnorm(30, 10), x = rnorm(30, 1), z = rnorm(30, -5))

# master dataframe
fixed <- data.frame(y = rnorm(30, 10), x = rnorm(30, 10), z = rnorm(30, 10), a = rnorm(30, 10))

# trying to add the random secondary values to the master data frame
d <- dplyr::mutate_at(fixed, c('y', 'x', 'z'), function(x){x + random$x})
```

I can add a single column to each of the columns, but when I try something like `x + random[, colnames(random) == x]` I get an error. It is not carrying over the column names and I cannot work out how to access them.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `base R` methods

```
fixed[names(random)] <- random + fixed[names(random)]
```

---

If we need to use `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
fixed %>% 
    select(names(random)) %>%
    map2_df(., random, ~.x + .y)
```

Comment: So this works, if you change the funs to `funs(. + random$.) Change your answer and I shall give Kudos. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @DanielPadfield If you want to have corresponding columns added together, use `map2_df from `purrr`